# How to make keep the active page bar highlighted?

Tags: html, css, blogger

```css
#menu ul{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style:none
}
#menu li a{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width:210px;
margin:0px 0px 3px 0px;
background:#0093dd;
color:#fff;
border:5px solid #dd127b;
line-height:50px;
font-size:1.3em;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:.1em;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none
}
#menu li a:hover{
background:#fff;
color:#0093dd;
text-decoration:none
}
#menu li a:active{
background:#dd127b;color:#fff;
text-decoration:none
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="..." title="...">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="..." title="...">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="..." title="...">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="..." title="...">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="..." title="...">...</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Dear developer, please help me to make the code right (without javascript) for highlight* the active page bar.

*background:#fff;color:#0093dd;text-decoration:none

I think some part of the code Im using it is incorrect or incomplete.

Using the present css and html code every function works fine such as color change for background and text on hover, color change for background and text on click.
Highlight the active page bar is the only function that I cant make it work.

It isnt the native blogger nav page bars. It is a mini app html placed in the header just below the #header (company logo).

Comment: Hello, I would suggest adding some code to your question and you may want to check this page for improving your question quality https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To say in short you have to use some Javascript magic :
1. Detect active page url using `window.location` object
2. Find corresponding `a` tag with `var item =document.querySelector("a[href=<found url is here>]")`
3. Add active class `item.classList.add("active")`
4. Describe `. active{...}` class in yous css code